# laravel passing data from view from controller

Tags: laravel

I have the following function in my controller

```
 public function approve($uin)
{
    $dir_uin = Approval::where('dir_uin',$uin)->get();


    return view('approvals.approve')->withApprovals($dir_uin);
}
```

and

in my view

```
     @php
@dd($dir_uin)
   @endphp
```

@dd returns a null and i have checked with tinker if the data is being fetched.

any reason why the data is not being passed to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the parameter as `approvals`, so in your view, it should be:

```
dd($approvals)
```

Which would be the value of `$dir_uin`.

Answer (score 1):

use this `return view('admin.profile', ["dir_uin" => $dir_uin]);`